# How can I define f(x) = some integral in python

Tags: python, numpy, symbolic-math

I'm trying to define the following function:

[image]

And this is the code I'm using:

```py
from scipy import integrate

def f(x):
    return integrate.quad(np.e**-t**2/2 * 1/2 * np.pi, x, 0)
```

This seems right to me but my next issue is that I get a `NameError`:

```py
NameError: name 't' is not defined
```

As I don't know what `t`, or `x` is supposed to be, I'm confused about how to go further.

Comment: `x` is defined as the parameter to your function, but you haven't said what `t` is supposed to be, which is why Python says it's not defined.  If you don't know what `t` is supposed to be, why did you include it in your code?

Comment: `scipy` is not symbolic math.

Answer (score 4):

Reading documentation to understand how to call a function is critical!  Looking at the doc for `scipy.integrate.quad`: https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.integrate.quad.html

it looks like the first argument is supposed to be a function, not an expression that returns a float.  So you need to define a function inside your function:

```
def g(t):
    return np.e**-t**2/2 * 1/2 * np.pi
```

and then make that the first parameter to `quad`:

```
def f(x):
    def g(t):
        return np.e**-t**2/2 * 1/2 * np.pi
    
    return integrate.quad(g, x, 0)
```

You could also do this with a `lambda`, which defines a function inline:

```
integrate.quad(lambda t: np.e**-t**2/2 * 1/2 * np.pi, x, 0)
```

Comment: Damn, you are faster than me.

Comment: OP, you can reference the tutorial here. 

https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/tutorial/integrate.html